# Does Python have an internal limit for recursive loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m trying to simulate a process with 5 steps where there is a chance to go to the next level. But if it fails, it falls back one level. The code works fine for chances around 50%+-20% and excecutes 1000000 times in a for loop without problems.

When i set the transition chance lower, it works maybe 5 times but 10 times is already pushing it and the kernel dies with a high chance.

I suspect that Python detects that a recursionloop was done too many times and stopps the kernel.

Why is it not working?

This is the code:

```py
import random
import numpy as np


c2=0
c3=0
c4=0
c5=0
fc=0
fs2_b=20
fs2=0
fs3_b=40
fs3=0
fs4_b=80
fs4=0
fs5_b=140
fs5=0
cost=0

c_dic={"high":
      {"di":
      {"c_base":0.12,"cap":0.7,"cost":10},
      "tri":
      {"c_base":0.08,"cap":0.7,"cost":10},
       "tet":
      {"c_base":0.05,"cap":0.7,"cost":15},
       "pen":
      {"c_base":0.03,"cap":0.7,"cost":15}
      },
       "low":
      {"di":
      {"c_base":0.0769,"cap":0.7,"cost":1},
      "tri":
      {"c_base":0.0625,"cap":0.7,"cost":1},
       "tet":
      {"c_base":0.02,"cap":0.7,"cost":1},
       "pen":
      {"c_base":0.003,"cap":0.7,"cost":1}
      }}

def chance(type, stage, fs,c_dic=c_dic):
    c_base=c_dic[type][stage]["c_base"]
    cap=c_dic[type][stage]["cap"]
    c=c_base+c_base*fs*0.1
    if cap>c:
        return c
    else:
        c_capped=cap+(fs-(cap/c_base-1)*10)*0.02*c_base
        if c_capped<0.9:
            return c_capped
        else:
            return 0.9

def di(type):
    global fs2,fs2_b,c2,fc,cost
    cost=cost+c_dic[type]["di"]["cost"]
    if fs2==0:
        fs2=fs2_b
        c2=c2+1
    if random.random()<chance(type, "di", fs2):
        fs2=0
        return tri(type)
    else:
        fs2=fs2+3
        fc=fc+1
        return di(type)
        
def tri(type):
    global fs3,fs3_b,c3,fc,cost
    cost=cost+c_dic[type]["tri"]["cost"]
    if fs3==0:
        fs3=fs3_b
        c3=c3+1
    if random.random()<chance(type, "tri", fs3):
        fs3=0
        return tet(type)
    else:
        fs3=fs3+4
        fc=fc+1
        return di(type)
        
def tet(type):
    global fs4,fs4_b,c4,fc,cost
    cost=cost+c_dic[type]["tet"]["cost"]
    if fs4==0:
        fs4=fs4_b
        c4=c4+1
    if random.random()<chance(type, "tet", fs4):
        fs4=0
        return pen(type)
    else:
        fs4=fs4+5
        fc=fc+1
        return tri(type)
        
def pen(type):
    global fs5,fs5_b,c5,c1,c2,c3,c4,fc,cost
    cost=cost+c_dic[type]["pen"]["cost"]
    if fs5==0:
        fs5=fs5_b
        c5=c5+1
    if random.random()<chance(type, "pen", fs5):
        r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6=c1,c2,c3,c4,fc,cost
        c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,fs5,fc,cost=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        return [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6]
    else:
        fs5=fs5+6
        fc=fc+1
        return tet(type)

n=10000
a=np.zeros((6,n))
for i in range(n):
    b=di("low")
    for j,val in enumerate(b):
        a[j,i]=val
```

Comment: Are you referring to your code raising a `RecursionError`? Yes, the depth of the function call stack (not necessarily as a result of recursion) is limited to 1000 frames by default, though you can modify it using `sys.setrecursionlimit`.

Comment: Python has a default limit of 1000 for recursion depth but that kind of crash is usually related to excessive memory usage.

Comment: there is no error, just the notification that the kernel died

Comment: How are you running the Python process? (if from the terminal on Linux, then there are ways to change the stack size)